# Method chaining on a new line in boo

Tags: boo

Is it possible to make method chaining in a new line, like you can do in C#?

```
var foo = bar
  .MethodOne()
  .MethodTwo()
```

Answer (score 4):

whitespace is not significant inside () so the following is legal boo code:

```
a = (bar
     .Foo()
     .Bar())
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use '\' symbol. See sample:

```
a = 123 \
       .ToString() \
       .Length
print a
```